# How to find the sum of n natural logarithms that are cubed?

Tags: summation, logarithms

I seem to be struggling with a mathematical problem. I need to evaluate this:

[image]

I know that the sum of all natural logarithms is *ln(n!)* and that the sum of all natural cubes is *(n(n+1)/2)^2* but these don't seem to be of any help in this situation. I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: In general: $\sum _{i=1}^n \log ^m(i)=\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^mH_n^{(-x)}}{\partial
   x^m}$ where:$H_n^{(-x)}$ is Harmonic Number of order x.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk and what is ∂ then?

Comment: Symbol of derivative,I yours case m-th derivative.Answer from CAS like Mathematica: $$\zeta ^{(3,0)}(0,n+1)-\frac{3 \gamma _2}{2}-3 \gamma _1 (\gamma +\log (2 \pi ))+\zeta
   (3)+\frac{1}{8} \left(-8 \gamma ^3+4 \log ^3(2 \pi )-12 \gamma ^2 \log (2 \pi )+\pi ^2
   \log (2 \pi )\right)$$

Comment: "sum of all natural logarithms" ? You mean $$\sum_{j=1}^n \ln(j)=\ln(n!)$$ Similar for the sum of the cubes.

Comment: @Peter your writing is correct but in my case the logarithm itself is cubed and not the j so I can't add them like that.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thank you for your help but sadly I'm not too familiar with the concept of Harmonic Numbers so I'm still struggling a bit

Comment: @KapitaiN I only wanted to point out the confusing formulations.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: at my math-pages https://go.helms-net.de/math/  scroll down to "Sums of like powers of logarithms - playing with indefinite summation" download (https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/BernoulliForLogSums.pdf) and see whether this is what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is a closed form.

If you want to get at least an order of magnitude, consider
$$\int_{i=1}^n \log^3(i) \,di < \sum_{i=1}^n \log^3(i) <\int_{i=1}^{n+1} \log^3(i) \,di $$ with 
$$\int \log^3(i) \,di= -6 i+i \log ^3(i)-3 i \log ^2(i)+6 i \log (i)$$

For $n=100$, the left integral is $5573.28$, the sum is $5622.17$ and the right integral is $5671.26$.